# sympy - Using "solve()" to find a value in the denominator

Tags: python, solver, sympy

I have been searching for a bit and I am at the point that I believe I may be asking google the wrong question.  If there is another thread out there that has this issue as well, please let me know.

I am relatively new to sympy, but the documentation is very good, so I haven't had any problems thus far.  I am trying to convert to Python from MATLAB and I am testing some scripts that have worked in MATLAB.  I am using Python 3.3.

I am trying to solve a relatively simple equality and I am failing.  When I run the script below, I only receive an empty list as the output.

```
# define the symbols we wish to use
se = symbols('se')

# assign some constants
D = S(0.24)
sn = S(38e6)
Q = S(0.64)

Dprime = 1.0 - D

mc = 1 + (se/sn)

# this is the expression that we wish to make equal to Q
expr = (S(1)/(pi * (mc * Dprime - S(0.5))))

# this should print the value for se
print(solve(Eq(expr, Q),se))
```

This block of code works perfectly right up until the "solve" function is executed.

```
>>> Eq(expr, Q)
             1                 
──────────────────── = 0.64
π⋅(2.0e-8⋅se + 0.26)
```

I have looked at the documentation and I have found that there are several flags that I could utilize.  I first tried the ones that I thought may be relevant.  I then tried the ones that I didn't think were very relevant.  I then tried them all.

I have also tried various operations on the inputs to the variables.  One of them that I left in is the S(), which I understand to be the "symplify" function.  Perhaps I over-did this one, but I suspect that one can't overuse the function.

The problem seems to be related to having a variable in the denominator.  I have tried many of the examples that are contained in the sympy documentation and all of them work for me, so I am fairly confident in the install itself.

Thank you for your time,

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, while searching for the answer, I came across a bit about using 'scipy' instead of 'sympy' for this.  As it happens, simply placing a `from scipy import *` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The flag you want is `rational=False`. I think this is a bug in SymPy, but probably your coefficient 2.0e-8 is too small.

Comment: I opened https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=4112 for this.

Comment: It looks like this issue has been fixed. It should work better in the next version of SymPy.